# Erro na execução de SQL PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando incluir registros pelo PHPMyAdmin, mas está retornando um erro estranho, conforme trecho abaixo:

> Erro
>   #1054 - Unknown column 'â€˜Fâ€™' in 'field list'

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `pe_orclinhas` (`id_orclinha`, `grupo`, `orcgrupo`, `bandeira`, `dc`, `orclinha`, `registro`) VALUES  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'Camry', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'Corolla', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'Etios', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'Hilux', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'SW4', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'RAV4', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),  (NULL, '38', '101', '47', ‘F’, 'Prius', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Esse `‘F’` ta meio estranho, ja tentou trocar por `'F'`?

Comment: Faça a alteração que o Francisco sugeriu, o erro está no ‘F’

Comment: Obrigado galera. Não sei de onde vieram esses sinais, já que eu só copiei e colei e nos anteriores deu certo. Valeu!